# Difference between "treffen" and "treffen auf"

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between `treffen` and `treffen auf` in the meaning of `to meet sb/sth`? The [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/treffen) simply translates both as `to meet` in this meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Ingmar's answer: you will find "treffen auf" used with people mainly in sports news to tell who plays against who:

> Ivan Lendl trifft im Finale auf den Weltranglistenersten Boris Becker.

and in politics news:

> [Emir trifft auf vertrauensvolle Kanzlerin](http://www.dw.de/emir-trifft-auf-vertrauensvolle-kanzlerin/a-17928131)

In the second example the author could have used "treffen" (without "auf") as well. He would then have stressed the sheer fact that the Emir met the Chancellor. With "treffen auf" he focusses on how the Chancellor acted in their meeting. Without "auf", i.e.

> Emir trifft vertrauensvolle Kanzlerin

the meaning would slightly change: the Chancellor would be "vertrauensvoll" in general, not specifically in that meeting.

Answer (score 5):

*Treffen* usually refers to meeting people. *Treffen auf* refers to a chance encounter and doesn't have to be used with people:

> Ich treffe mich mit Hans. Die Geschäftspartner trafen sich zu einem Gespräch.
>
> Der Jäger traf auf eine frische Spur. Am Abend traf der Wirbelsturm auf Land. In der zweiten Runde des Turniers treffen die Gewinner der ersten Runde auf einander. Die Soldaten trafen auf heftigen Widerstand.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ingmar and Matthias answer: `treffen auf` can also indicate that you meet primarily for the reason of eating or drinking something.

> Wir treffen uns auf ein Bier / einen Burger / ein Glas Wein

siehe [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?query=auf+ein+bier+treffen)

Comment: To be precise: this is about the reflexive form "sich treffen auf".

Answer (score 1):

We have first to device the following expression: `to meet sb/sth` into (1) `to meet sb` and (2) `to meet sth`.

**In Case of (1) `to meet sb` with translation `treffen`:**

is used in the German language, for the case if a person has been met, without this was expected.

`a colleague by chance, on the road, meet on the street`

`einen Kollegen zufällig, unterwegs, auf der Straße treffen`

**In Case of (2) `to meet sth` with translation `treffen`:**

is used in the German language, for the case if an object like projectile, bullet or a blow hits an person and this person is injured by this object.

is used in the German language, for the case if an object like projectile, bullet or a blow hits an other object and which gets damaged because of this meet.

`the shot hit him in the back`

`der Schuss traf ihn in den Rücken`

**In Case of (1) `to meet sb` with translation `treffen auf`:**

is used in the German language, for the case if a person has been shoved and falls against another person.

-> In this case the Person falls and meet the other person because of his falling movement.

`When you fall to another person incident.`

`Beim Sturz auf eine andere Person auftreffen.`

**In Case of (2) `to meet sth` with translation `treffen auf`:**

is used in the German language, for the case if a person has been shoved and falls to floor.

-> In this case the Person falls and meet on a surface.

`When falling on a sharp edge incident.`

`Beim Sturz auf eine scharfe Kante auftreffen.`

I think for clarify with the information that "treffen auf" is more precisely translated back to "to carom" in english and "to carom" is translated in german to "auftreffen".